# OpenShift DIY cartridge and LEMP installation

Tags: openshift

Im trying to install the following components on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) (Free plan: 3 small gears):

- Nginx
- Php - php-fpm
- MySQL
- Wordpress

Since a [DIY](https://developers.openshift.com/en/diy-overview.html) cartridge is limited to 1 gear and can't be scaled, do I need to install all components on one gear, or should I install each component on a separate gear? What's the best approach to install a custom LEMP stack on this server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install all of the components on one gear.  If you install the database on a separate gear, without using a scaled application, then you would run into issues connecting to the database without using port forwarding between your gears.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose this means that a DIY application is limited to 1 Go only, whereas a similar standard openshift app (for ex. using wordpress, mysql and php) would be able to scale up to three gears and use the 3 Go of space, right?

Comment: Correct.  DIY gears are not scalable.

Comment: Will this be possible in the future? This makes openshift _de facto_ really limited. For example, I have to install LEMP with only 1 Go left, which is almost impracticable.